# $A=\mathbb{R}^n-\{a\}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have seen at many places that $A=\mathbb{R}^n-\{a\}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is path connected. But how do we prove it? I understand that we have to show that there is a continuous map $\gamma:I\rightarrow A$ between any 2 points of $a_1, a_2\in A$ such that $\gamma(0)=a_1$ and $\gamma(1)=a_2$. $(I=[0,1])$ But I have no idea on finding such $\gamma$. Any hints?

Comment: what would you do if you are in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Then I can take the straight line that joins the 2 points.

Comment: Then start like that and let us know what would be the problem...

Comment: You can find more in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected

Answer (score 4):

For any two points $P_1, P_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{a\}$,if $a \notin \overline{P_1P_2}$ ($a$ does not belong to the segment $\overline{P_1P_2}$) then we can set the path:

$$ \gamma : t \mapsto P_1 + t(P_2 - P_1)$$

which is continuous and that $\gamma(0) = P_1$, $\gamma(1) = P_2$.

If  $a \in \overline{P_1P_2}$ then pick a point $Q$ that does not belong to the segment $\overline{P_1P_2}$. From the previous construction we know that there exist 
$$\gamma_1 : t \mapsto P_1 + t(Q - P_1) $$
and 
$$\gamma_2 : t \mapsto Q + t(P_2 - Q) $$

We can see that the path function
$$ \gamma : t \mapsto \begin{cases} \gamma_1(2t) & \mbox{if } 0 \leqslant t < \frac12 \\ \gamma_2(2t - 1) & \mbox{if } \frac12 \leqslant t \leqslant 1\end{cases}$$
satisfies $\gamma(0) = P_1$, $\gamma(1) = P_2$ and is continuous over $[0,\frac12)\cup (\frac12, 1]$. It is also continuous at $\frac12$ since both sides tends to $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have no idea on finding such $\gamma$.

I have a hunch about the problem here. Maybe you're looking for a function $\gamma(a_1,a_2,t)$ that is continuous in all of its variables, including $a_1$ and $a_2$. For example, in $\mathbb R^n$, you observed that you can take the straight line that joins the two points. That is a continuous function in $a_1$, $a_2$, and $t$. So maybe you're hoping to amend this function to work in $\mathbb R^n-\{a\}$ similarly, using a single, continuous formula.

If you could do that, then by fixing $a_2$, you would have a continuous function $$f:(\mathbb R^n-\{a\})\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n-\{a\}$$
such that for all $a_1$, $f(a_1,0)=a_1$ and $f(a_1,1)=a_2$. In other words, $f$ would be a [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) from the identity function to a constant function. But such a function cannot exist on $\mathbb R^n-\{a\}$! We say that $\mathbb R^n-\{a\}$ is not [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space). (I'm not sure of an elementary proof of this fact, but it's aside from the point.)

Since $\gamma$ cannot be a continuous function of $a_1$ or $a_2$, you can't build it out of polynomials, sine and cosine, etc. The best you can do is a definition by "if-then" cases. Looking for such a definition should lead you to an answer like corindo's.